# PHP memcached session replicas

Tags: php

I am setting up my memcached servers and am looking into how have as much uptime is possible if one of my servers fails. I use the memcacheD extension (2.2.0)

Below is the code I am going to use (Haven't deployed yet). I have questions for a few of the lines below.

```
session.save_handler = memcached

#2 servers; which one is the replica? What happens is the replica fails? Does it matter which one fails?
session.save_path = "192.168.134.38:11211,192.168.134.234:11211"

memcached.sess_consistent_hash=1

#What does this actually do?
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas=1

#Do I need this?
memcached.sess_binary=1
```

Comment: http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_behavior.html#MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding. If I choose 1 what does this do with 2 servers. It says it stores n copies; but where?

Comment: "on the ‘n’ next servers specified in your server list". So with 1 it states that it will save it on the "current" and on the next server.

Comment: So if I had 3 it would be 2? What does sess_binary do?

Comment: If you have 3 servers and you want to write to all of them you need to put 2 indeed. Not sure about binary protocol though, but it does not look relevant to HA